# How to split read/write queries to Slave/Master datasources using Prisma?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma, master-slave

I'm using Prisma 3.15 with NestJS and need to split queries to two different data-sources. One is read-only replica and another is master database.

#### I don't want to manage these manually on each prisma call!

How can I split them automatically?

I can define two separate clients in PrismaService like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readClient: PrismaClient,
    private writeClient: PrismaClient
  ) {
    this.readClient = new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {db: {url: process.env.PRISMA_READ_DB_URL}},
    });
    this.writeClient = new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {db: {url: process.env.PRISMA_WRITE_DB_URL}},
    });
  }
```

###### But how can I split queries between them?

Can I override prisma modules like this?

```
  get user() {
    // Do something with the user!!!

    return this.readClient.user;
  }
```

Comment: instead of overriding, you can add new methods `get userReadonly () { return this.readClient.user }`

Comment: If so, I have to choose datasource manually everytime I call prisma. How can I do this automatically?